# Oracle to DB2 , HOW TO DO IT

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I got query bellow and first of all , what does setence bellow means :

```
Create or replace FUNCTION GPRS7003(
    -->> In Parameters --
    pe_sTexto       VARCHAR2,
    pe_sDelimitador VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

    -->> Variáveis <<--
    v_sRetorno VARCHAR2(32767);

    -->> Cursor de Seleção de Partições da Variável <<--
    CURSOR CUR_RETORNO_PARTICOES IS  
        SELECT DISTINCT(t.V_SCOLUNA) AS PARTICAO
          FROM (SELECT *
                  FROM TABLE(GPRSG001.GPRS7001(pe_sTexto,
                                               pe_sDelimitador))) t;

-->> Início - Função para Retornar Variável Particionada Distinta <<--
BEGIN
    -->> Passando pelo Cursor de Seleção de Partições da Variável <<--
    FOR c_retorno_particoes IN CUR_RETORNO_PARTICOES LOOP
        -->> Checando se é a Primeira Partição <<--
        IF (v_sRetorno IS NULL) THEN
            -->> Gerando a String de Retorno <<--
            v_sRetorno := c_retorno_particoes.PARTICAO;
        ELSE
            -->> Gerando a String de Retorno <<--
            v_sRetorno := (v_sRetorno || pe_sDelimitador || c_retorno_particoes.PARTICAO);
        END IF; -->> Fim - Checando se é a Primeira Partição <<--
    END LOOP; -->> Passando pelo Cursor de Seleção de Partições da Variável <<--
    -->> Retornando as Partições <<--
    RETURN v_sRetorno;
END GPRS7003;
```

I dunno what does **FOR c_retorno_particoes IN CUR_RETORNO_PARTICOES LOOP** means, also i dunno have huge background in Cursor .

Actually  id like someone exlplain another way to rid of cursor and use transact -sql

I've tried to use that one in DB2 Database but that sintaxy doesnt recognize in DB2 V11.1 . Also i enabled  ORA compatibility .

Would be great if someone explain or give me an example using cursor

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A remark about your observations concerning PL/SQL emulation in Db2. You write:

> I dunno what does FOR c_retorno_particoes IN CUR_RETORNO_PARTICOES
>   LOOP means, also i dunno have huge background in Cursor . ...
>
> I've tried to use that one in DB2 Database but that sintaxy doesnt
>   recognize in DB2 V11.1 . Also i enabled ORA compatibility 
>   ....

This Oracle syntax for PL/SQL cursor is: `for record in cursor-name loop...`

That syntax is described in Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm).

My Db2 V11.1 on Linux supports this Oracle syntax when **correctly** enabled for Oracle compatibility.  If your installation rejects this Oracle syntax then you must have made some mistake with your Db2 configuration. A common mistake is that the DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA variable was not effective **before** creating the Db2 database.

Db2 does not currently support everything in Oracle's syntax, but this form of a cursor seems to be emulated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence `for c_retorno_particoes in CUR_RETORNO_PARTICOES LOOP` is going to run (loop) once for each row in this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t.V_SCOLUNA) AS PARTICAO
  FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE(GPRSG001.GPRS7001(pe_sTexto, pe_sDelimitador))) t;
```

On each run (loop) the row will be available through a variable named `c_retorno_particoes`.

So, let's say you want to "print" each `PARTICAO` value to the console, you can do this:

```
for c_retorno_particoes in CUR_RETORNO_PARTICOES LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(c_retorno_particoes.PARTICAO);
end loop;
```

Comment: So c_retorno_particoes  is a new cursor inside of CUR_RETORNO_PARTICOES  ?

Comment: 'c_retorno_particoes' is a row variable, containing a row from the cursor which can be processed inside the loop. The row variable is not available after the cursor loop is complete. [Documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS553)  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment than an answer, but just too long for a comment.

First thing to look at is **GPRSG001.GPRS7001**. This is a function that gets a text and a delimiter and returns rows. I suppose it's the separate words it returns, i.e. from the text `'abc def abc ghi'` and the delimiter `' '` it would get the values `'abc'`, `'def'`, `'abc'`, and `'ghi'`.

The function you are showing has a cursor that selects distinct values from the above, i.e. `'abc'`, `'def'`, and `'ghi'`. Then in a loop these get combined with the same separator again, so we'd end up with `'abc def ghi'` (or `'ghi abc def'` or any other order, as no `ORDER BY` clause is specified).

Oracle's PL/SQL is a programming language working closely with the database. I don't think that DB2 has something like this, but I don't actually know. You'll probably have to write a recursive query to get the single words and use `LISTAGG` then to combine the distinct words into a new string.